# Holding a mutex lock after all writes are finished

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, mutex

I have a question about thread safety and mutex locks in C++. I know that at the simplest level, a mutex lock should be held at any point where there could be simultaneous reading and writing to the same memory. However, I also know that each core has its own cache, so I picture the mutex lock as a way to ensure that all threads "agree" on the state of the data at any time point.

The thing I am unsure about is what happens when all the writing operations are done. Is it safe to use the data then without owning the mutex lock?

See example below. Based on my shallow understanding, it feels like the last line could produce undefined behavior since the code is not aware of all the writing operations that have been done in the threads. I.e. what if the arr in the main thread cache looks different from the arr's in the worker thread caches.

```
std::mutex mtx;
std::vector<int> arr;

std::list<std::thread> threads;
for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i) {
   threads.push_back([&](){
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
      // Change arr here.
   });
}
for (auto& thread : threads) {
   thread.join();
}
// Can I use arr here without owning the mutex lock?
std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
```

So my question is if the above example is safe, and if not, can I ever use arr without holding onto a mutex lock?

Comment: If there's only one thread running, both reading and writing is always safe. You don't need to worry about the caches; the machine handles it.

Comment: Releasing a mutex is a sync-point. I think your code is valid.

Comment: A mutex protects from data races. If only reads are talking place, there can be no data race, like in your example. On top of that, if there is only one thread accessing the data, there can also be no data race.

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate, I'm voting to reopen. The question asks whether it is safe to use data without mutex after join. For that the join operation has to impose memory barriers at least. It probably is safe, it should be, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @wohlstad, this seems to be the correct answer to my question (as opposed to the duplicated suggestions that don't address the question explicitly),
I found this link that explains how releasing a mutex lock is affecting the caches https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70055886/does-a-mutex-lock-guarantee-that-a-thread-will-always-store-updated-values-into

Comment: "I picture the mutex lock as a way to ensure that all threads "agree"..." Yes, but don't try to picture points in time. What the threads really should agree on is, no thread ever unlocks the mutex unless/until the shared data are in a state that you would want other threads to see. And, no thread ever even _looks_ at the shared data without having locked the mutex.

Comment: @SolomonSlow "And, no thread ever even looks at the shared data without having locked the mutex." This comment could be a bit misleading without context, since it on the surface seems to imply that I would need to own the mutex lock at the last line of my example code in the original post above.

Comment: @4-bit, Good point. If N threads share the same set of variables, and then one of the threads `join`s all of the others, then you're right; The survivor no longer needs to lock the mutex when accessing the previously-shared variables after the N-1st `join` call returns. I don't always think about `join` because a lot of code I've worked on has been server code or embedded code for which, power failures are more likely than orderly shutdown requests. (see https://dslab.epfl.ch/pubs/crashonly.pdf or https://lwn.net/Articles/191059/ )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this code is safe.

The C++ standard's description of `std::thread::join()` includes:

> The completion of the thread represented by `*this` synchronizes with (6.9.2) the
> corresponding successful `join()` return.

That implies that if some operation X happens before (in the technical sense of the C++ memory model) the completion of the thread, and some operation Y happens after the return of `join()`, then X happens before Y.  In your program, this means that the operations on `arr` within the various threads will all happen before the access in the main thread which follows the `join()`.  Thus there is no data race.

For the implementation, this means in effect that the cleanup code that terminates a thread must contain a release barrier before it notifies the thread waiting on `join()`, and the code for `join()` must have an acquire barrier after receiving that notification.  In practice, the necessary barriers are likely to be automatically provided by the OS services that exit and wait for threads.